# Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'. > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, android-studio

I am getting the following error while trying to import bundle in Android studio. Does anyone know the solution?

> Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'. > Process
> 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1